# Ways to prevent broken pipe?

Tags: java, exception, sockets, pipe

```
ClientAbortException:  java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe
```

If I am wright, this happens when user aborts current operation or makes another request, before the last one is finished.

Can this reflects on browsing user or is this (always) *just* a Catalinas exception?

Are there any ways to avoid this exception?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try defining a filter for all resources in your webapp, and catch & discard the exception there. I'm not sure if it will work, but give it a try.

In 99% of the cases this exception can be ignored, because it's mainly called by user disconnects (i-net breaks, user hits stop, closes browser, etc)

Comment: I guess this will work for not getting this error in logs, but I am more curious if there's a possibility that user will notice this error.